# Dataflow job was stuck for two days

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a `dataflow` streaming job, running on single instance, that was stuck for two days, I couldn't find any reason for that in job's logs.

After some digging, I found that underlying VM instance was restarting every few minutes. Finally `VM` was migrated, which solved issue with `dataflow` job.

My question is : will increasing the number of instances work around the issues with underlying infrastructure?

> jobid: 2017-12-22_05_53_58-16575873104426487312

Comment: Hi, were there any changes to your GCP project's network configuration(s) or firewall rules during this time?

Comment: Hi Andrew,
No, nothing like that happened. I've double checked the project's activity log

Comment: Hi Kamil - I wish I could explain to you what happened with your job - it seems very odd.  The Dataflow service itself recorded starting the job on 12/27 - 5 days after it was created. I'm looking into whether there may be a known issue with misbehaving VMs on single instance jobs.